# Mahout - Error when try out wikipedia examples

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath, mahout

Note this post is similar to

[Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656289/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-classpath)

but different error message.

When I try to run Wikipedia Bayes Example from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Wikipedia+Bayes+Example

When I ran the following command :

```
lis-macbook-pro:mahout-distribution-0.8 Li$ mahout wikipediaXMLSplitter -d examples/temp/enwiki-latest-pages-articles10.xml -o wikipedia/chunks -c 64
```

I got error message:

```
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, running locally
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/Li/File/Java/mahout-distribution-0.8/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.8-job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/Li/File/Java/mahout-distribution-0.8/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-jcl-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerFactory]
Oct 21, 2013 4:25:47 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter warn
WARNING: Unable to add class: wikipediaXMLSplitter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wikipediaXMLSplitter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.addClass(MahoutDriver.java:236)
at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:127)
Oct 21, 2013 4:25:47 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter warn
WARNING: No wikipediaXMLSplitter.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
Unknown program 'wikipediaXMLSplitter' chosen.
```

I am using Hadoop 1.2 and Mahout 0.8.
mahout-distribution-0.8/bin has been added to $PATH.
$MAHOUT_LOCAL is set to "True", so it runs locally.

I dont know why I got "Unable to add class: wikipediaXMLSplitter"

Answer (score 1):

To the original question:

The reason you are seeing the error:

There's no entry for wikipediaXmlSplitter in $MAHOUT_HOME/src/conf/driver.classes.default.props. Add the following line to this file:

```
  org.apache.mahout.text.wikipedia.WikipediaXmlSplitter = wikipediaXmlSplitter : wikipedia splitter
```

You should now be able to invoke via:

```
mahout wikipediaXmlSplitter
```

Note, the case sensitivity in 'wikipediaXmlSplitter'.

There's an error on Mahout wiki wherein it reads as 'wikipediaXMLSplitter' as opposed to 'wikipediaXmlSplitter' which has since been fixed on the new Mahout website at http://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/wikipedia-bayes-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the full name
org.apache.mahout.text.wikipedia.WikipediaXmlSplitter
rather than just WikipediaXmlSplitter